The inverse of $I+T$ where $T$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator
I am doing an exercise from problem 40 in Brezis' Functional analysis.

Let $E\,$ be a Hilbert space and $T$ be a Hilbert-Schmidt operator from $E$ to $E$. Assume the kernel of $I+T$, denoted $N(I+T)$, is $\{0\}$. Show that $I+T$ is bijective, and its inverse is $(I+T)^{-1}=I+S$ for some $S\,$ that is also a Hilbert-Schmidt operator.

If $T$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator, then it is compact, and from $N(I+T)=\{0\}$ we know $I+T$ is bijective and thus invertible by the Fredholm alternative.
But then I don't know how to express its inverse using $I$ and a Hilbert-Schmidt operator $S$.
Maybe writing it as $I+P(T)$ where $P(T)$ is a polynomial of $\,T$, and use that products and linear combinations of Hilbert-Schmidt operators are still Hilbert-Schmidt?

Symbolically, at least, one can analogize to the geometric series to write $(I+T)^{-1}=I-T+T^2-\cdots$ and thus take $S=-T+T^2-\cdots =-T(1+T)^{-1}$. (The last certainly exists, since you already established that $(1+T)$ was invertible.)

You can use (one of) the resolvent formulas: If $A$ and $B$ are bounded invertible operators, then
$$
A^{-1}-B^{-1}=A^{-1}(B-A)B^{-1}.
$$
If you read this from right to left, it is easy to see why it is true. In your case,
$$
(I+T)^{-1}-I^{-1}=(I+T)^{-1}(I-(I+T))I^{-1}=-(I+T)^{-1}T.
$$
Thus $S=-(I+T)^{-1}T$. Since the Hilbert-Schmidt operators form an ideal and $T$ is Hilbert-Schmidt, the operator $S$ is also Hilbert-Schmidt.

Let $I+S$ be the inverse of $I+T.$ Then
$$I=(I+T)(I+S)=I+S+T+ST$$ Thus
$S=-T-ST,$ which implies that $S$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator.
